# Sending email with attachments in Ruby with the Pony Gem

Tags: ruby, email, pony

I am writing a script that is going to be sending out emails to a list of people and with this email there is going to be an attachment.

I keep running into this issue:
`/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:942:in 'check_response': 552 sorry, that message size exceeds my databytes limit (#5.3.4) (Net::SMTPFatalError)`

The attached file is only 110kb

Code:

```
    Pony.mail(
        :to => to,
        :from => 'Me <me@me.com>',
        :subject => html_entity_decoder.decode(options[:subject]),
        :html_body => "#{options[:body]}".html_safe,
        :attachments => {File.basename("#{attachment}") => File.read("#{attachment}")},
        :headers => { "Content-Type" => "multipart/mixed", "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "base64", "Content-Disposition" => "attachment" },
        :via => :smtp, 
        :via_options => {
          :address        => ADDRESS,
          :port           => '25',
          :enable_starttls_auto => true,
          :user_name      => USERNAME,
          :password       => PWD,
          :authentication => :plain,
          :domain         => DOMAIN
          }
      )
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is telling you that the mailbox you are sending it to, has run out of space.

The error is an SMTP error : 
      552 Requested mail action aborted: exceeded storage allocation

outlined in the rfc http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt.

So either the mail box is full or you are sending something that will not fit in it

Comment: Hmm thats odd... I'm sending a test email to myself in my Gmail account... and I know I have TONS of room there. I changed the SMTP port to 25 instead of 587 (default) and now I am getting an execution expired error...

Comment: This on a server , test machine , whats the setup ?

Comment: I am testing locally... I am going to put this on a server and see what happens...

Comment: Yeah, just threw my script up on a server and getting the same original error and I tried it on both ports (587 & 25). I know for a fact there is no way in hell that my mailboxes are full... I tried sending the attachment to my personal gmail and my work email.

Comment: Thanks for the help man! Come to find out the SMTP host we were using had an extremely small limit on file size for attachments... they bumped it up and everything is working now!

Comment: Well the issue I am running into now is that when I send the email out with the attachment, nothing appears in the body of the email and even though my email client sees that there is an attachment, it doesn't appear for me to click on to download. Revised code above

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
:attachments => {File.basename("#{attachment}") => File.read("#{attachment}")},
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "multipart/mixed", "Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "base64", "Content-Disposition" => "attachment" }
```

Probably this will solve your problem.